# Object reference not set to an instance of an object request.GetResponse()

Tags: c#

```
public static string Method_Name(
        string requestMethod, 
        string requestUrl, 
        string requestBody = null, 
        Dictionary<string, string> requestHeader = null, 
        string requestUserAgent = null, 
        Boolean isContentType = false)
    {

        string responseString = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            Uri requestUri = new Uri(requestUrl);
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
            request.Timeout = 60000;

            if (requestHeader != null)
            {
                foreach (string key in requestHeader.Keys)
                {
                    request.Headers.Add(key, requestHeader[key]);
                }
            }

            request.Headers.Add("X-FD-TrustLevel", "trusted");
            request.Headers.Add("X-FD-Version", "1.0");

            request.Method = requestMethod;

            // For MAS 1.0 POST Call
            if (isContentType)
            {
                request.ContentType = @"application/json";
            }


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestUserAgent))
            {
                ((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = requestUserAgent;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
            {
                Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                string requestString = requestBody;
                stream.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(requestString), 0, requestString.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }



/* ERROR */ HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseString = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AnswersExceptionCollection.GetInstance().AddException(ex);
        }

        return responseString;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following message when code execution reaches `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`:

> *Error occurred - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

I am aware why this kind of error happens, but I am not able to find the root cause in this particular case. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can try wrapping the call in a `try { HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); } catch (WebException webEx) {}` block and check the `Response` and `Status` properties of the WebException.

Comment: From the call stack, is the exception _in your method_ or somewhere _deeper_?

Comment: Its not an ecxeption, its an error

Comment: @futurenext110: If it's not an exception, where/how are you getting that error message?

Comment: on the command prompt where I am running the application: <Application_Name> Error occurred - Object reference not set to an instanc
e of an object.

Comment: @futurenext110: And the application continues running after the indicated line?

Comment: @futurenext110: Sounds pretty much like an exception to me ... just trying to imagine the symptoms so I can think of possible reasons.

Comment: Please tell us the rest of the error after `<Application_Name> Error occurred - Object reference not set to an instance of an object` - the call stack.

Comment: Nothing. The program terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Problem must be in these two lines

```
Uri requestUri = new Uri(requestUrl);
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
```

Verify with breakpoint after executing these lines that whether request is null or not. 
If it is null then your provided URL may not exists or may have some other problem.

Regards,
Pavan.G

Comment: No The request is not null, it has the following value: +  request {System.Net.HttpWebRequest} System.Net.WebRequest {System.Net.HttpWebRequest}

Comment: once check without any parsing the request. i.e request.GetResponse(). Check it with debug point.

Answer (score -1):

It seems your initiation on the request

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
```

needs some details of the kind of request. If you're trying to get HttpWebResponse, you have to catch response from **HttpWebRequest**. here is a quote from [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse.aspx).

> NoteNote
>
> The WebRequest class is an abstract class.The actual behavior of
>   WebRequest instances at run time is determined by the descendant class
>   returned by the WebRequest.Create method.For more information about
>   default values and exceptions, see the documentation for the
>   descendant classes, such as HttpWebRequest and FileWebRequest.

So that meant you'll get this clear if you create the request like that

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri)
```